# Blocking JavaScript execution for a set period of time without needless computation

Tags: javascript, client-server

I want to block client-side JavaScript execution for a specified amount of milliseconds (e.g. *sleep*) in an entirely synchronous manner, by putting some JavaScript at the top of the page.

Nothing should happen while the waiting is being performed. The page should not continue to load. It should not be responsive. Also, I want to have 1-10 milliseconds of precision if possible, and the waiting time can be over 1000 milliseconds.

The standard "solution" for this problem is... to ask a different question because this is NOT something you normally want to do. What you normally want to do is something along the lines of `await Promise.delay(1000)`.

So I'm fully aware of the problems of doing this, fully aware it's a terrible ideas in almost all circumstances, but I still need to do it. And just to put your soul at ease, the page will only be used by a headless browser, so no users will be harmed in the execution of this hack.

An actual solution to the problem would be:

```
while (expectedTime > Date.now()) { }
```

Which works very well. But it has the side-effect of doing lots of unnecessary computation when all I want to do is just tell the event loop to *stop*.

I think the trick might be to force the page to do some synchronous I/O for the first couple of 100ms of ms and then resort to the above tactic, but I'm not certain how to accomplish this. I can use the server too, if that helps.

Comment: WEB Javascript context has no "sleep" like function available which would put the inner event loop to idle state and save CPU cycles. What's the reason why your webpage should be waiting?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `async/await` syntax, take a look at this.

```js
async function stop_fn() {
  var a = 99999999
  var b = 11111111
  console.log('hello there')

  //This will stop the execution without CPU blocking
  await new Promise(next=> setTimeout(()=> next(), 4000))

  console.log('After 4000ms', a)

  //Another 4000ms stop
  await new Promise(next=> setTimeout(()=> next(), 4000))
  console.log('after 4000ms more, please stop it', b)

  return 'end of this'
}
stop_fn()
```

Comment: This is quite a bit late, but this won't work. I want to block the event loop, as I mentioned in the question. I actually mentioned this kind of thing as something that would not work for me.

Comment: Then use a infinite while for N seconds if you want to block the event loop, but that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Could you please read a question next time, until the end, before answering? I repeatedly mention that this is something that normally doesn't make sense, but I need to do it anyway. I actually give a while loop as an example of a possible solution, but I state multiple times that the problem with this is the needless computation.

Answer (score -1):

```
//random blocking function 
function blockCpu(ms) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(true) {     
        if (new Date().getTime() > now +ms) 
            return; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is the *exact thing I mentioned in the question*. I already know you can do this. I asked for something better. Because this results in churning the CPU for ages, hurting other processes.